# Can I delete a list from a nested list?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have created a nested list. The parent list contains 5 sublists. Can and how could I delete the last sublist from the parent list? I have tried:

```
 tableau[tableau.Count - 1].Clear();
```

The items are removed, but the parent list count remains the same at 5. I also tried .RemoveAll, but that requires some sort of parameter that I do not know how to enter.

```
List<List<string>> tableau = new List<List<string>>();

        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Aard00", "Aard01", "Aard02", "Aard03", "Aard04", "Aard05", "Aard06", "Aard07" });
        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Bard00", "Bard01", "Bard02", "Bard03", "Bard04", "Bard05", "Bard06", "Bard07" });
        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Card00", "Card01", "Card02", "Card03", "Card04", "Card05", "Card06", "Card07" });
        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Dard00", "Dard01", "Dard02", "Dard03", "Dard04", "Dard05", "Dard06", "Dard07" });
        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Eard00", "Eard01", "Eard02", "Eard03", "Eard04", "Eard05", "Eard06", "Eard07" });
```

Comment: removing a list and clearing a list are different operations. also you will want to start reading error messages completely in order to understand them or get help with them.  the error message surely does not indicate `some sort of parameter`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [List.Remove()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-7.0)

```
 tableau.Remove(tableau[tableau.Count - 1]);
```

or [List.RemoveAt(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=net-7.0)

```
 tableau.RemoveAt(tableau.Count - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RemoveAt(lastIndex).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<List<string>> tableau = new List<List<string>>();

        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Aard00", "Aard01", "Aard02", "Aard03", "Aard04", "Aard05", "Aard06", "Aard07" });
        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Bard00", "Bard01", "Bard02", "Bard03", "Bard04", "Bard05", "Bard06", "Bard07" });
        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Card00", "Card01", "Card02", "Card03", "Card04", "Card05", "Card06", "Card07" });
        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Dard00", "Dard01", "Dard02", "Dard03", "Dard04", "Dard05", "Dard06", "Dard07" });
        tableau.Add(new List<string> { "Eard00", "Eard01", "Eard02", "Eard03", "Eard04", "Eard05", "Eard06", "Eard07" });

        Console.WriteLine("tableau BEFORE:");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, tableau.Select(x => string.Join(", ", x))));
        Console.WriteLine();
        /*
        tableau BEFORE:
        Aard00, Aard01, Aard02, Aard03, Aard04, Aard05, Aard06, Aard07
        Bard00, Bard01, Bard02, Bard03, Bard04, Bard05, Bard06, Bard07
        Card00, Card01, Card02, Card03, Card04, Card05, Card06, Card07
        Dard00, Dard01, Dard02, Dard03, Dard04, Dard05, Dard06, Dard07
        Eard00, Eard01, Eard02, Eard03, Eard04, Eard05, Eard06, Eard07
        */

        tableau.RemoveAt(tableau.Count - 1);

        Console.WriteLine("tableau AFTER:");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, tableau.Select(x => string.Join(", ", x))));
        /*
        tableau AFTER:
        Aard00, Aard01, Aard02, Aard03, Aard04, Aard05, Aard06, Aard07
        Bard00, Bard01, Bard02, Bard03, Bard04, Bard05, Bard06, Bard07
        Card00, Card01, Card02, Card03, Card04, Card05, Card06, Card07
        Dard00, Dard01, Dard02, Dard03, Dard04, Dard05, Dard06, Dard07
        */

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```